# Responsive Navigation Bar 100% Width

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a navigation bar which is made of buttons/checkboxes which makes it responsive,I either want the bar to take the whole width of the the browser, which has to be responsive(so shrinks as the browser gets smaller) or just to be centred.
HTML:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Index_files/style.css">
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Expand Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" width="100%">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="Index_files/Images/Coldplay Logo Transparent.png" style="height:100%;"></a>          </li>

    <li>
        <a>Music ￬</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/musicTracks.html">Music Tracks</a></li>
            <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/musicVideos.html">Music Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/Tour.html">Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/Feed.html">Feed</a></li>

    <li><a>Store ￬</a>
        <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/storeTickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/storeMerch.html">Merchandise</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="Index_files/Webpages/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/*ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    display:table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Create horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 1px;

}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    align-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    min-width:140px ;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #303133;
    text-decoration: none;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In css: 
    #menu{
       width: 100%;
       }

Comment: Thank you for trying but this didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Well, you will have to set the height and the background-color of the div as well of course. Otherwise it will not appear. Not really sure what you are trying to do here but I made a Jsfiddle for you to check out: https://jsfiddle.net/qzr5s7m9/